# How can i filter wordpress users by custom feild?

Tags: filters, users, list

I'm displaying users (authors) on a page. how can I add a filter based on user custom feilds?

```php
    <?php
                // THE USER QUERY ARGS
                $args = [
                    'role'   => 'author',
                    'number' => -1,
                ];
                // THE USER QUERY
                $user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);

                // THE TOTAL SUBSCRIBERS NUMBER
                echo '<h3 class="font-weight-bold">Total Listed Shops: ' . $user_query->get_total() . '</h3>';
                echo '<hr>';

                // THE USER LOOP
                if (!empty($user_query->get_results())) {
                    foreach ($user_query->get_results() as $user) {
                        // ACF PREFIX & FIELD DATA FROM USER PROFILE
                        $location = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'yourprefix_location', true);
                        $city = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'yourprefix_city', true);
                        $images = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'blog_group', true);
                        $archive_url = get_author_posts_url($user->ID);
                        echo '<div class="card bg-light p-4">';
                        // USER DATA DISPLAY
                        echo '<h1><a href="' . $archive_url . '" title="' . __('View all posts by ', 'pippin') . $user->display_name . '">' . $user->display_name . '</a></h1>';
                        // ACF DATA DISPLAY
                    
                        echo '<p>ADDITIONAL INFO:</p>';
                        echo '<p>City: <span class="text-danger">' . $city . '</span></p>';
                        echo '<p>Location: <span class="text-danger">' . $location . '</span></p>';
                        echo '<h6>e-mail: <span class="text-danger">' . $user->user_email . '</span></h6>';

                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<hr>';
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `meta_key` and `meta_value` query arguments.

```
$args = [
    'role'   => 'author',
    'number' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'yourprefix_location',
    'meta_value' => 'somevalue' 
];
```

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/#custom-field-parameters